# Routing doesn't work without attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

**EDIT:** [An issue has been opened](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/1795) on GitHub to clarify the docs with the information in the answer.

I'm trying to set up routing in my .NET Core MVC app (for an API). I believe I have everything configured correctly, but no routes work (all return 404) unless the action has a routing attribute explicitly set. This same problem is mentioned [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2016/03/15/asp.net-core-mvc-6-lessons.aspx), but he doesn't know what fixed the problem.

> I put the attributes back on, it worked. I removed them, it didn't. Eventually through some magical incantation of removing and re-adding route configuration - switching it off and back on again in other words - `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()` worked without routing attributes. Not sure what happened there.

Here is a simplified version of what I have. What's the problem? Why isn't routing working without attributes set?

In this example, I'm attempting to `POST` to `/login/register`.

`Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                         .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = 
                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

I also tried specifying the route manually:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "default",
        "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Login controller:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("register")] // only works with this here
    public IActionResult Register([FromBody]RegisterModel model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to configure "Routing".This is how ASP.net knows where the URL maps to which Controller. There are several ways to configure routing. You've found two of them. [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and [Route Table](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api). NB my examples are for WebAPI, but the concept is similar.

Comment: @Aron `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()` supposedly configures that ([source](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions/#meth-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute)). I did try with an explicit route inside `app.UseMvc()`, but that still didn't work.

Comment: @vaindil, Just for troubleshooting, remove the policies and try the default `services.AddMvc()` and work from there. gradually add in new pieces one at a time and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @vaindil Without seeing your attempt at a route table, I can't tell what you did wrong. Also, have you tried decompiling/view the source to `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute`?

Comment: @Nkosi I removed every single thing from those two methods in `Startup.cs` except `services.AddMvc()` and `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()` (no config for either), routing still fails.

Comment: @Aron [Here's the source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L43) for `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute`. That's the template I tried: `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`. I also tried simply `{controller}/{action}/{id?}`.

Comment: Does it fail even when you set the default to `{controller=Login}/{action=Register}/{id?}`.

Comment: If you don't have the Route attribute on your action, you'll need to get rid of the Route attribute on the Controller, or add an [action] token there.

Comment: @OdeToCode That was it. That's not at all clear from the docs, I never would have guessed that to be the problem. Add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging to know how to correctly use tags and avoid forcing tags into the question title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}` route will already map the controller and action to `/Login/Controller`. However, if you add a `[Route]` attribute on the controller, you indicate that you want to start building a new route and the default route will not apply anymore. Therefore you'll either have to remove the attributes from both the controller and action or add it to both. You might also want to use the `[action]` route token as well:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginController : Controller
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Using `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]` fixed the problem for me in a project where I was mixing Razor pages and Web API controllers. The official [Web API tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) doesn't include the `[action]` token in the examples shown, so routes were not working unless you explicitly used the `[Route(...)]` attribute on each action.